# Claims transformation in ADFS 3.0 by making a call to REST API

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity, adfs, claims

We have a ASP.NET Web API (REST service) in our enterprise that gives us the list of coarse-grained claims for a user that we want to inject into the adfs token before passing the token onto the application. Does anyone know if making a rest call is possible using the Custom attribute store (by passing param's to the custom attribute store from the Claims rule language in ADFS 3.0) ?

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated!

> Thanks,
>   Ady.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to make the REST call from the Custom Attribute store. For those who are still wondering about this can look at the below code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IdentityModel;

using Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;

namespace CustomAttributeStores
{
    public class CoarseGrainClaimsAttributeStore : IAttributeStore
    {
        #region Private Members

        private string API_Server = "https://<Server Name>/API/";

        #endregion

        #region IAttributeStore Members

        public IAsyncResult BeginExecuteQuery(string query, string[] parameters, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {   
            string result = string.Empty;

            if (parameters == null)
            {
                throw new AttributeStoreQueryFormatException("No query parameter.");
            }

            if (parameters.Length != 1)
            {
                throw new AttributeStoreQueryFormatException("More than one query parameter.");
            }

            string userName = parameters[0];

            if (userName == null)
            {
                throw new AttributeStoreQueryFormatException("Query parameter cannot be null.");
            }

            //Ignore SSL Cert Error
            //TODO: Need to set the SSL cert correctly for PROD Deployment
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=  (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                //The url can be passed as a query
                string serviceUrl = API_Server  + "GetAdditionalClaim";
                serviceUrl += "?userName=" + userName;

                //Get the SAML token from the API
                result = client
                            .GetAsync(serviceUrl)
                            .Result
                            .Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                result = result.Replace("\"", "");
            }

            string[][] outputValues = new string[1][];
            outputValues[0] = new string[1];
            outputValues[0][0] = result;

            TypedAsyncResult<string[][]> asyncResult = new TypedAsyncResult<string[][]>(callback, state);
            asyncResult.Complete(outputValues, true);
            return asyncResult;
        }

        public string[][] EndExecuteQuery(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            return TypedAsyncResult<string[][]>.End(result);
        }

        public void Initialize(Dictionary<string, string> config)
        {
            // No initialization is required for this store.
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you use for your rule language to invoke this attribute store?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this with the claims rules language.

This is somewhat of a hack but you could write the claims to e.g. a DB and then use a [custom attribute store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895358.aspx)

If you have access to WIF on the client side, you can augment the claims there e.g. [Adding custom roles to windows roles in ASP.NET using claims](http://brockallen.com/2013/01/17/adding-custom-roles-to-windows-roles-in-asp-net-using-claims/).